# React keeps re-rendering my components that i made by mapping over an object.entries(useState variable)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have written code in react js and it works (it renders a simple table) but the table elments keep rerendering every second and when i try to highlight something it unhighlights immediately

this is a react table that basically pulls from lichess api
it renders a table but the the td and trs keep refreshing constantly

i tried this

```
import './Recent.css';
import { React, useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSort, faSortUp, faSortDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';

function Recent() {
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState({});
  const [headers, setHeaders] = useState([""]);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [vState, setVState] = useState('default');
  const [dState, setDState] = useState('default');
  const [rState, setRState] = useState('default');

  const fetchRatings = () => {
    fetch('lichesslinkthatyoudontgettosee')
      .then (response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then (data => {
        setRatings(data);
        setHeaders(["Variant", "Date", "Rating"]);
        setLoaded(true);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRatings()
  }, []);

  function vCycle(vState) {
    if (vState === 'default') {
        setVState('dsc');
        setDState('default');
        setRState('default');
    } else if (vState === 'dsc') {
        setVState('asc');
    } else {
        setVState('default');
    }
  }

  function dCycle(dState) {
    if (dState === 'default') {
        setDState('dsc');
        setVState('default');
        setRState('default');
    } else if (dState === 'dsc') {
        setDState('asc');
    } else {
        setDState('default');
    }
  }

  function rCycle(rState) {
    if (rState === 'default') {
        setRState('dsc');
        setVState('default');
        setDState('default');
    } else if (rState === 'dsc') {
        setRState('asc');
    } else {
        setRState('default');
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{display: loaded ? 'flex' : 'none'}}>
      <h2>Most Recent</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={() => vCycle(vState)}>{headers[0]} <span><FontAwesomeIcon fixedWidth transform="shrink-3" icon={vState === 'default' ? faSort : vState === 'asc' ? faSortUp : faSortDown} /></span></th>
            <th onClick={() => dCycle(dState)}>{headers[1]} <span><FontAwesomeIcon fixedWidth transform="shrink-3" icon={dState === 'default' ? faSort : dState === 'asc' ? faSortUp : faSortDown} /></span></th>
            <th onClick={() => rCycle(rState)}>{headers[2]} <span><FontAwesomeIcon fixedWidth transform="shrink-3" icon={rState === 'default' ? faSort : rState === 'asc' ? faSortUp : faSortDown} /></span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {Object.values(ratings).filter(o => o.points.length).map((item) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                    <td className="variant">{item.name}</td>
                    <td className='date'>{item.points.at(-1)[1] + 1 + "/" + item.points.at(-1)[2] + "/" + item.points.at(-1)[0].toString().slice(2, 4) }</td>
                    <td className='rating'>{item.points.at(-1)[3]}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
           }) ?? null}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

// const displayInfo = () => (
  
// )

export default Recent;
```

it keeps refreshing all the trs and tds
how can i fix this

```
import './App.css';
import Recent from './components/Recent';

function App() {
  return (
    <Recent />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `node-fetch` in a front-end project?

Comment: Can't see anything here that would cause re-renders. How is your `<Recent />` component rendered in its parent? The re-renders are probably coming from further up the component hierarchy

Comment: Agree with @Phil, but please be *extremely careful* using `uuidv4()` as a `key` in JSX - that's not a stable identifier so React won't be able to track it correctly. Try and use an identifier from your `item` object

Comment: im using node-fetch to fetch from lichess api to display ratings history in a table

Comment: :O deleted the uuidv4 and changed to item.name so thx

Comment: But React's effect hooks run in the client and `node-fetch` **only** runs in Node.js. On the client side, simply use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

delete uuidv4() as key and change to item.name

Comment: I do not see at all how this could cause a render loop

Comment: There is no way using `uuidv4()` as the key causes re-renders. See https://codesandbox.io/s/still-browser-nh3yfh?file=/src/App.js:939-941

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

the code is well and nothing here that would cause re-renders try tracking your code using console.log to see if there is really re-renders and the parent component and check you css file

```
       {Object.values(ratings).filter(o => o.points.length).map((item) => {
           
            console.log('item.name');

            return (
              <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                <td className="variant">{item.name}</td>
                <td className='date'>{item.points.at(-1)[1] + 1 + "/" + item.points.at(-1)[2] + "/" + item.points.at(-1)[0].toString().slice(2, 4) }</td>
                <td className='rating'>{item.points.at(-1)[3]}</td>
              </tr>
            )
       }) ?? null}
```

else you can wrap all the tr elements inside a React.memo

recent.jsx

```
return (
  <table> 
    <TableRows someData={trProps} />
  </table>
)
```

Table rows component:

```
const TableRows = React.memo( ({someData}) => /* Triggers update only if 'someData' changes */
      <> { someData.map( data => <tr>{data}</tr> ) } </>
    )
```